# What triggers the 'allow this program to make changes to your computer' message?

Tags: windows-7

So in windows 7, when a program tries to 'make changes to your computer', a dialog box will pop up asking if you wish to permit it.

My question is this; What *exactly* triggers this? (What action of the program?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message is a [UAC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691(v=ws.10).aspx) prompt.

This is used by Windows Vista and later to prompt the user for permission before running an application with elevated permissions.

There are a number of ways this can be triggered:

1. If you explicitly run an application with "run as Administrator"
2. If you run a program with an [application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx) that specifies a requirement for Administrative permissions.
3. If the application you are running has an AppCompat database entry specifying that it requires elevation
4. If the *filename* of the application you are running meets some heuristics that determine it to be an installer (for example if it contains the string "setup")

Depending on your settings, Windows may also display a UAC prompt before allowing you to change system settings in the Control Panel.

If a program attempts certain protected actions (in particular writes to protected files or registry keys) without being run with elevated permissions, the writes will end up in the user's virtual store, rather than in the protected location (I learned this the hard way, attempting to support some legacy software).

Answer (score 0):

If a program needs to call certain **tasks** then it will trigger a UAC prompt.

This list is taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control):

```
Running an Application as an Administrator
Changes to system-wide settings or to files in %SystemRoot% or %ProgramFiles%
Installing and uninstalling applications
Installing device drivers
Installing ActiveX controls
Changing settings for Windows Firewall
Changing UAC settings
Configuring Windows Update
Adding or removing user accounts
Changing a user’s account type
Configuring Parental Controls
Running Task Scheduler
Restoring backed-up system files
Viewing or changing another user’s folders and files
Running Disk Defragmenter
```

Comment: This is not the full story. This is a list of actions you can take from Explorer.exe or the Control panel, that will trigger the UAC. It does _not_ address what causes third part applications to trigger the UAC.